# ActiveAndroid "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatAp"

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I am trying to use **activeandroid**, everything work fine on android 6 and 7
but when i try to run it on **OS 5** i get:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23**

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.koa.testactive"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: and now i tried it on OS 4 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

maybe the ActiveAndroid caused this problem,change the version of it to the newest and retry

Comment: it is the newest one

Comment: what is the newest ActiveAndroid version ?